# Is there any way to limit fcm notification for a specific screen?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a question about the FCM notification limit. Is there any way that I can limit FCM notifications for a specific screen? For example, if there are three screens, screen A, screen B, and screen C, the notification should be received on-screen A and B but should not be received while user is viewing screen C.

If I am right, I think it has to check if screen C is showing on the device before sending notifications. So how can I check which screen is showing and how to limit notifications for a specific screen?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to intercept all fcm if app is in foreground, to check if app is in foreground you can use this in your `FCMService`

```kotlin
if(ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle == Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
   LocalBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(Intent())
```

you need to add lifecycle dependencies for it

```
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
    kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"
```

then you can register a broadcast receiver from your screen C and send explicit broadcast from FCMService.

Note that the broadcast receiver is registered on screen C `onResume` and unregistered on `onDestroy`.

More info on how to use explicit BroadcastReceiver [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts)

Comment: Would that be an efficient method if I want to receive notifications for all screens, but not for when user is looking at screen C?